# How do you move committed changes from a branch to master as pending changes?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, feature-branch

I was implementing a new feature, for which I created a new branch, and made a few commits onto it, and pushed. I now wish to continue working on this feature in master, in the form of pending / uncommitted changes. Pending because it needs more work before I commit. How do I do this?

When I finally commit, the revision history of master should just indicate one commit, as if I never created another branch or made intermediate commits. How do I do this?

The manual way is to create a second git workspace, open master in one and the branch in the other, and copy-paste each modified file. Is there an automated way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just continue working on the branch you've already created? You can squash everything down to a single commit when you're done before you merge it into `master`.

Comment: I generally like to code in diff view, with the head of master in the left pane and my code in the right pane, so I'm aware of what changes I'm making. This doesn't work in a branch because the left side of the diff in Xcode no longer shows the head of master; it shows the head of the branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'll give the commands, then what they are really doing and why this achieves what you want.  I assume below that the feature branch is just called `branch`—change the name given to `git merge` if it has some other name.

```
git status               # and make sure everything is committed on your branch
                         # do any extra commits here if required

git checkout master      # change the current branch/commit, index, and work-tree
git merge --squash --no-commit branch
```

(In `git merge`, `--squash` implies `--no-commit` anyway, so you can omit the second flag argument here.  I included it more for illustration.  Moreover, `--squash` means *do the merging action in the index and work-tree, but don't make a merge commit.*)

You may, depending on your tools, want to do `git reset` (which defaults to a `--mixed` reset with `HEAD` as the commit) to copy the `HEAD` commit back into the index, so that plain `git diff` shows you everything, and `git status` shows everything as *not staged for commit*.

#### Long

It's important to note, here, that there isn't really such a thing as *pending changes*.  Git doesn't store *changes* at all.  What Git stores are *commits*, and each commit is a complete snapshot of all files.  When you ask Git *what changed*, you must tell Git about *two* commits, or at the least, two trees-full-of-files.  Git then figures out, from those two inputs, what's different in snapshots A and B.  Then Git tells you those differences—but A and B remain full snapshots.  In some ways, none of this matters—you see changes when you want, and snapshots when you want.  But if your mental model matches what Git really does, you'll have fewer mysteries to solve: your own job will be easier.  The most important way this matters is to remember: **In order to see changes or differences, you must provide two inputs.**  Sometimes, one of those inputs is implied.  Sometimes, *both* of them are implied!

This last is the case with a simple `git diff` or `git diff --cached` / `git diff --staged`: Git compares the index to the work-tree (plain `git diff`), or the `HEAD` commit to the index (`--staged` or `--cached`).  The option, if any, determines the two inputs.  That is, Git takes two of the three things from this list:

- the `HEAD` commit, which is a real commit, containing all files in the special Git-only, frozen/read-only form;
- the index, which is essentially the *proposed next commit*, and contains a copy of all the files, also in the Git-only form but not quite frozen;
- the work-tree, which has your files in their ordinary useful form.

With two of these things in hand, Git compares them and tells you what's different.  The `git status` command runs, as part of its job, *both* of these two `git diff`s (with certain options always set, such as `--name-status` and `--find-renames=50%`) and summarizes the results: the output from `git diff --staged` are *changes staged for commit* and the output from `git diff` are *changes not staged for commit*.

You can also manually run `git diff HEAD`.  This chooses `HEAD` and your work-tree as the two inputs: you explicitly named one of them, `HEAD`, in the arguments, and the other is implied.  That compares the frozen `HEAD` contents to the unfrozen, normal-format, work-tree contents, and shows you the difference.  Again, Git is comparing full snapshots: the *second* one is the live work-tree, snapshotted by the process of diffing.

(Aside: what you want to do, in my opinion, is probably the wrong way to go about it.  You can often make your own job easier by committing early and often.  Doing diffs is a good idea, but you can do them from base-commit to tip-commit, i.e., across a span of commits, to assess the overall result.  You can then use a interactive rebase, or—my preferred method—additional branches, to reconstruct the smaller commits into a more sensible series of commits.  But much of this is personal preference.  It sounds like your Xcode tool could work a lot better than it is doing; the way you're using it is not *wrong*, it's just terribly limiting.)

#### How and why this works

I started writing a longer post but it got out of hand, so I'll just say: see some of my other StackOverflow answers for how Git makes commits out of the index, not the work-tree, and how these commits update the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached.

Git's merge is itself also a pretty big topic.  However, we can say that merging uses the *index* to achieve its merge result, with the *work-tree* playing a secondary role, mainly for the case where there are merge conflicts.

A real merge—that is, a `git merge` that does a full three-way merge and will, in the end, make a new commit of type *merge commit*—makes its new commit with *two* parents.  These two parents are two of the three inputs that went into computing the merge result.  The third input is implied by the other two; it's the *merge base*.  Git finds the merge base on its own, using the commit graph.  Git then compares the merge base to the `--ours` and `--theirs` branch tips, as if using two `git diff --find-renames` commands: one from base to ours, one from base to theirs.

Ignoring issues like added, deleted, or renamed files, the comparison of these three commits produces a list of who changed which files.  If *we* changed some file that they didn't change, or *they* changed some file that we didn't, merging these is easy: Git can just take our file, or their file.  If neither of us changed the file at all, Git can take any of the three versions of the file (merge base, ours, or theirs).

For the difficult case—we both changed some file—Git takes the merge base to start with, and *combines* our changes and their changes and applies the combined changes to the merge-base copy.  If our changes and their changes touch different *lines*, the combining is straightforward and Git declares the result a success (even if it makes no sense in reality).  If we and they both changed the *same* lines, Git declares a merge conflict.

The merge conflict case is the messiest.  Here, Git leaves *all three input files* in the index, and writes the conflicted merge to the work-tree.  Your job, as the human running `git merge`, is to come up with the correct merge, however you like.  You can use the three index copies of the file, or the work-tree copy, or all of these.  You resolve the merge yourself and then use `git add` to write the correct result into the index, replacing the three unmerged copies with a single merged copy.  That resolves this conflict; once you have resolved all conflicts, you can finish the merge.

If you run `git merge` with `--no-commit`, Git will do as much merging as it can on its own—which might be all of it—and then stop, the same way it would for a merge conflict.  If there were no conflicts, this leaves both the index and work-tree in a ready-to-commit state.  (If there were conflicts, the `--no-commit` option has no effect: Git was already going to stop, with the mess left behind, and still stops, with the mess left behind for you to fix.)

In all of these cases, though, Git leaves behind a file in the `.git` directory, telling Git that the *next* commit—whether from `git merge --continue` or `git commit`—should have *two* parents.  That makes the new commit a *merge commit*, which will tie together the two branches:

```
             I--J   [master pointed to J when we started]
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- branch
```

That's not what you want.  So, we use `git merge --squash`, which tells Git: *Do the merge work as usual, but instead of making a **merge** commit, arrange for the next commit to be an **ordinary** commit.*  That is, if Git were to make a new commit `M`, it would look like this:

```
             I--J--M   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- branch
```

For no particularly good reason, `--squash` inhibits the commit even if the merge goes well.  So after `git merge --squash`, the index and work-tree are updated, but you can make more changes to the work-tree, use `git add` to copy the updated files into the index, and only when you are done, use `git commit` to make the new commit.

(For a more trivial merge, where Git would default to doing a fast-forward, `--squash` inhibits the fast-forward mode as well, as if by `git merge --no-ff`.  So `--squash`, without `--no-ff` and without `--no-commit`, suffices.)

The final `git reset`, if used and needed, just copies the `HEAD` commit back into the index.  That is, you probably want your tool to compare the `HEAD` commit to the work-tree, as if you were running `git diff HEAD`.  If the tool compares the index to the work-tree instead, you can get the same effect by de-updating the index to match `HEAD`, after the `--squash` operation updated it.

Comment: I upvoted this. Also thanks so much for the effort to help a stranger!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a merge into `master` and then using your preferred diff tool to diff the commit history?

The merge into `master` will be a commit. But as long as you do not `push` the changes to a remote (e.g. 'origin') you can always reset the merge using `git reset HEAD~2` to abandon the merge commits.

One additional note, the 'HEAD~2' is an example of the number of commits to reset back to in the commit history. If your merge commit put you 'x' number of commits ahead of your remote you would replace the '2' with the number of commits a `git status` reports you are ahead of your remote.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the habit of checking diffs before committing, to verify. If I merge onto master, and then make changes, the diff for the pending changes will be relative to after the merge, but I want them after the master. So let's not pursue your suggested approach. It's also too convoluted. Is there a single command to run that does what I originally asked -- take all the commits to the branch and apply them on master as pending changes. My git knowledge is basic, so I want to keep things simple.

Comment: I thought it would be a good way to increase your git skills by using Git's feature of undoing commits (ones not pushed to an origin).  But I understand your perspective and agree it's more convoluted than you were probably looking for.  I did not know a simpler way... but I'm sure there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a number of valid ways to do this. I'd like to describe a short one using *patches* to transfer your code changes from the feature branch.

```
cd $the-root-of-your-project
git checkout feature-branch
git format-patch <the-commit-since-you-began-the-feature>
```

This will create one *patch* file per commit. (Hint: The commit you need to enter in the last command is the one *before* the first one you want to transfer. See `since` and `revision range` in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch for details.)

Secondly, I suggest you `cat` all that `*.patch` files into one.

Thirdly, get the changes of that accumulated *patch* file into the index of *master*:

```
git checkout master
patch -p1 < accumulated.patch
git diff
git add .
...
```

`patch` is the one from *bash* and `-p1` is necessary to strip the git-specific path prefix in the *patch* file off.

Comment: Thanks. The two branches that have diverged a bit. Can this be taken care of when applying the patch, or is it simpler to first merge changes from master into the branch, and then generate the patch file?

Comment: You have found a disadvantage of this approach, since applying the patch is basically a 2-way merge, hence it does not take the common history of master and branch into account. I.e. every merge conflict needs your attention. So yes, it will be beneficial to merge master into branch first.